# ckeditor 5 - how do I convert a mention to a custom text element?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to work with CKEditor 5 and mentions. I am already using the "mention" plugin and the basic configuration (taken from [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html)) is working fine. I can see the autocomplete box and the output data is valid.

My goal is to convert a mention to some custom content.

For example this input

```
Hi @John!
```

Should come out as

```
Hi <span data-mention-id="john" class="whatever-mention">[~john.smith@company.com]</span>
```

I have been trying all sorts of things with downcast and viewWriter but I can't make it work. For example, trying `viewWriter.createPositionAt()` throws `view-writer-invalid-position-container` when I'm passing an `AttributeElement` as target.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am not able to figure out how to change the text that gets displayed and am not able to remove the marker.